# How to get default simply routing in laravel 5

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5, laravel-routing

How to set routing so that for every url like example.com/controller/method call proper method in given controller automatically, not by set this separately for each case in routes.php?
Eg. If url is example.com/product/edit, I would like call method edit in controller ProductController and similary for every action/method?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add into routing routes for each Controller, but you don't have to add routes for each method separately.

You can create:

```
Route::resource('product', 'ProductController');
```

and you will have automatically generated routes for each REST actions.

There is also method `controller` that could be used this way

```
Route::controller('product', 'ProductController');
```

but it's deprecated since Laravel 5.2 so you should not use it anymore becuase it might be removed in future releases.

Reference: Documentation for [RESTful resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)